# How to store action in a different state?

Tags: redux, react-redux

So I have one action called `getUserData` and another one `getAllUserData` first will get only data for the logged user and second will get data for all users from DB. Now I want to be able to call and dispatch both. But if I call `getAllUserData` over `getUserData` all the state is changed and `getUserData` data is lost and replaced with `getAllUserData` data. I want to keep both in store. Is that possible?

Here are my actions

```
export function getUserData(dispatch, getState) {
  const state = getState();
  const { user_id, token } = state.auth;
  return axios.get(USER_DATA(user_id), {
    headers: { authorization: token }
  }).then((response) => {
    dispatch(setBusinessData(response.data.data.userData[0]));
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Couldn't get user data.");
  });
}

export function getAllUserData(dispatch, getState) {
  const state = getState();
  const { token } = state.auth;
  return axios.get(USER_ALL_DATA, {
    headers: { authorization: token }
  }).then((response) => {
    let result = [];
    response.data.map(o => {
      result.push(o.userData);
    });
    merged = [].concat.apply([], result);
    dispatch(setUserData(merged));
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch(console.log("Couldn't get all user data."));
  });
}
```

And here is my reducer

```
module.exports = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_DATA':
      return action.userData

    case 'SET_BUSINESS_DATA':
      return action.businessData

    case 'UPDATE_USER_DATA':
      return [
        ...state,
        action.updatedUser
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

here is the state

```
Object {
  "alerts": Array [],
  "auth": Object {
    "email": "user@mail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YjI3NjAyNDAwOWI1NDA5ZjMwNzAzZWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1Mjk5MTQ0NjkwNjl9.r3hOOkx2I3qbVw_9ICRqsrSm9BLxUgachJgWax8MBDk",
    "user_id": "5b276024009b5409f30703ef",
  },
  "userData": Object {
    "_id": "5b2761be009b5409f30703f9",
    "address": Array [
      Object {
        "_id": "5b2761be009b5409f30703fb",
        "city": "London",
        "number": "14",
        "postcode": "N12 4NB",
        "street": "Chantelham Road",
      },
    ],
    "businessData": Array [
      Object {
        "_id": "5b2761be009b5409f30703fa",
        "position": "Hr Manager ",
        "type": "Coffee company",
      },
    ],
    "education": Array [],
    "experience": Array [],
    "firstName": "Josh",
    "lastName": "Wright",
    "phone": 747489345,
    "role": "employer",
    "skills": Array [],
    "volunteer": Array [],
  },
}
```

In reducer I've tried to create a `newState = []` for `'SET_USER_DATA'` but that returned an error

Comment: How is your app `state` looks like? It's definitely should be an object instead of array

Comment: Yes it is an object

Comment: Can you update a question with the shape of your state? Cuz in reducer i see it's like an array

Comment: check now as I've pasted part of the state

Answer (score 0):

Your state should access users by their ID and also keep track of the currently logged-in user's ID:

```
{
  ... 
  currentUserId: 'userId1',
  userData: {
    'userId1': { /* data of this user */ },
    'userId2': { /* data of this user */ },
    ... 
  }
 ...
}
```

Alternatively you can put this in your `state.auth`, this this seems to contain the current user ID already.

This way the two actions don't interfere. But you have to be careful if fetching one user results in more properties (for that user) than fetching all of them.

Comment: and where do you suppose to do this?

Comment: @MarkusHayner You'd need to change the two user-fetching actions and the reducer. Once the approach of separating 1) user data and 2) the indicator for the logged in user is clear, it should be obvious. This is a way to normalize your state. I can try to explain more if the approach isn't clear.